# Last tabularx column raggedright with memoir?

Tags: tables, memoir, tabularx

In the 3-column `tabularx` output produced with the following source that uses the `memoir` documentclass, how do I get the 3rd (last) column to be typeset ragged right rather than justified?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{3in}{l|>{\raggedright}X|p{0.725in}}
\toprule
\textbf{Source} & \textbf{Targets}          &\textbf{Locations}
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
09  & 99, 199, 299, 399, 499, 599, 699, 799 & boxes 5, 119, 135--136
\\\hline
200 & 399   & box 23
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx table wants ragged right last column]

I tried modifying the `tabularx` so as to begin...

```
\begin{tabularx}{3in}{l|>{\raggedright}X|>{\raggedright}p{0.725in}}
```

... but that causes an error:

```
./tabularx.tex:14: Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.14     \end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In the final column you need to use `\arraybackslash` to reset `\\` back to ending a table row, or use `\tabularnewline` rather than `\\`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{3in}{l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.725in}}
\toprule
\textbf{Source} & \textbf{Targets}          &\textbf{Locations}
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
09  & 99, 199, 299, 399, 499, 599, 699, 799 & boxes 5, 119, 135--136
\\\hline
200 & 399   & box 23
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't read about`\arraybackslash` with `\raggedright` in `memman` (page 224) carefully enough. The usage was right there!